# How to Compare and delete Rows from a CSV file in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

> This is what the CSV file looks like : [image]

> How to delete all the `title`, `description` rows, **except** leaving the 1st one . I am using `Pandas` as of now, so a solutions based on it will be helpful.

> This is what I tried, but it didnt worked :

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df =  df[df.name = "title"] 
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly find the indexes of title and description

```
index_list = df.index[df['title'] == 'title' or 
             df['description'] == 'description'].tolist()
```

Now drop all the rows that contain title and description.

```
df.drop(index=index_list, inplace=True)
```

At last write the data-frame in file

```
df.to_csv(file_name, index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the rows where the title is not 'title' :

```
df =  df[df['title'] != "title"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully the first `title,description` are assigned as headers of the dataframe.

In any case, you can use `df.drop()` with some added zing to drop certain rows that meet your criteria:

Input:

```
    title   desc
0   abc2    something1
1   title   desc
2   abc2    something2
3   title   desc
4   abc3    something3
```

Using criteria where any row's title is literally called "title" and dropping them:

```
df = df.drop(df[df.title == "title"].index)
```

Output:

```
    title   desc
0   abc2    something1
2   abc2    something2
4   abc3    something3
```